# How can i get content from outside an HTML tag with xpath

Tags: html, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I was studying web-scrapy and I got into the following situation

```
<br>
<b style="" xpath="1">Data de autuação</b>
<br>
29/06/2018 - 17:53:48
<br>
<br>
<b>Estado</b>
```

How can i get text '29/06/2018 - 17:53:48' with xpath?

Comment: Don't post images, please. Edit your question with the actual html of both cases.

Comment: Ok, sorry is my first post/question :)

Comment: Let's say the parent of the your above code is a div then you can try `//div/text()[4]`.

Answer (score 0):

Since the text isn't between tags and to avoid whitespace nodes you can use something like this :

```
normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(string(//body),//b[@xpath="1"]/text()),//b[last()]/text()))
```

We get the whole text inside the body tag with string and trim the unecessary parts with substring commands. We finish with a normalize-space to have a clean result.